# diff: output.txt: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, data-structures

im trying to run this code on my linux server using terminal, but i keep getting this error.

- diff: output1.txt: No such file or directory
- diff: output3.txt: No such file or directory

what im trying to do is multiply two matrices by taking inputs from any .txt file given that contains matrices inside and output the answer to another .txt file. Also checking that multiplication might contain an error like multiply 2*2 by 3*2 and give the error on another .txt file.

it is like checking cases.

here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

//function to check if a number (in string format) is double or not
bool is_double(const string& s)
{
   istringstream in(s);
    double d;
    return in >> d >> ws && in.eof();  
}

//main function
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
   //check if all required command line arguments are passed
   if (argc < 4)
   {
       cerr<<"error"<<endl;
       return -1;
   }

string inputfile1(argv[1]); //input file containing first matrix
   string inputfile2(argv[2]); //input file containing second matrix
   string outputfile(argv[3]); //output file containing matrix obtained after multiplication
   //extract names of files
   inputfile1=inputfile1.substr(inputfile1.find("=")+1);
   inputfile2=inputfile2.substr(inputfile2.find("=")+1);
   outputfile=outputfile.substr(outputfile.find("=")+1);  
   /*cout<<"input file1:"<<inputfile1<<endl;
   cout<<"input file2:"<<inputfile2<<endl;
   cout<<"output file:"<<outputfile<<endl;*/

   //file stream for files
   ifstream infile1(inputfile1.c_str(),ifstream::in);
   ifstream infile2(inputfile2.c_str(),ifstream::in);
   ofstream outfile(outputfile.c_str(), ofstream::out);
   if(!infile1 || !infile2 || !outfile)
   {
       cerr<<"error"<<endl;
       return -1;
   }
   double** inmatrix1; //input matrix 1
   double** inmatrix2; //input matrix 2
   double** outmatrix; //output matrix
   int m=0,n=0; //dimensions of input matrix 1
   int p=0,q=0; //dimensions of input matrix 2

   //extract dimensions from input file 1
   string line="";
   while(getline(infile1,line)!=NULL)
   {
       //count columns
       int len = line.size();
       int cols = 0;
       for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
       {
           if(!isspace(line[i]))
               cols++;
       }
       n=cols;
       m++;
   }  
   //cout<<"matrix1 dimensions:"<<m<<" "<<n<<endl;

   //extract dimensions from input file 2
   line="";
   while(getline(infile2,line)!=NULL)
   {
       //count columns
       int len = line.size();
       int cols = 0;
       for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
       {
           if(!isspace(line[i]))
               cols++;
       }
       q=cols;
       p++;
   }  
   //cout<<"matrix2 dimensions:"<<p<<" "<<q<<endl;

   //check if multilplication possible
   if(n!=p)
   {
       cerr<<"error"<<endl;
       return -1;
   }

   //allocate space for matrices
   inmatrix1 = new double*[m];
   for(int i = 0;i<m;++i)
   {
       inmatrix1[i]=new double[n];      
   }
   inmatrix2 = new double*[p];
   for(int i = 0;i<p;++i)
   {
       inmatrix2[i]=new double[q];      
   }
   outmatrix = new double*[m];
   for(int i = 0;i<m;++i)
   {
       outmatrix[i]=new double[q];      
   }
   //read data from files into matrices
   cout<<"Reading matrix 1..."<<endl;
   //matrix 1
   infile1.clear();
   infile1.seekg(0,ios::beg);
   line="";
   int j=0,k=0;
   while(getline(infile1,line))
   {
       stringstream ss(line);
       string token;
       k=0;
       while(getline(ss,token,' '))
       {
           //check if double or not
           if(!is_double(token))
           {
               cerr<<"error"<<endl;
               return -1;
           }
           else
           {
               inmatrix1[j][k]=atof(token.c_str());
               k++;  
           }          
       }
       j++;  
   }
   cout<<"Matrix 1 read!"<<endl;

   //matrix 2
   cout<<"Reading matrix 2..."<<endl;
   infile2.clear();
   infile2.seekg(0,ios::beg);
   line="";
   j=0,k=0;
   while(getline(infile2,line))
   {
       stringstream ss(line);
       string token;
       k=0;
       while(getline(ss,token,' '))
       {
           //check if double or not
           if(!is_double(token))
           {
               cerr<<"error"<<endl;
               return -1;
           }
           else
           {
               inmatrix2[j][k]=atof(token.c_str());
               k++;  
           }          
       }
       j++;  
   }
   cout<<"Matrix 2 read!"<<endl;

   //print both matrices
   cout<<"Matrix 1:"<<endl;
   for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
   {
       for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
       {
           cout<<inmatrix1[i][j]<<" ";
       }
       cout<<endl;
   }
   cout<<"Matrix 2:"<<endl;
   for(int i=0;i<p;i++)
   {
       for(int j=0;j<q;j++)
       {
           cout<<inmatrix2[i][j]<<" ";
       }
       cout<<endl;
   }  

   //multiply two matrices
   for(int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
   {
       for(int j = 0; j < q; ++j)
            for(int k = 0; k < n; ++k)
            {
                outmatrix[i][j] += inmatrix1[i][k] * inmatrix2[k][j];
            }
   }

   //print result to file  
   for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
   {
       for(int j=0;j<q;j++)
       {
           outfile<<outmatrix[i][j]<<" ";
       }          
       outfile<<endl;
   }  

   //close files
   infile1.close();
   infile2.close();
   outfile.close();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does your code have to do with your `diff` problem?

Comment: when i run it on the terminal, i get this error. @molbdnilo

Comment: already existed @drescherjm

Comment: Unrelated, you have a pretty lenient compiler if `while (getline(infile1, line) != NULL)` actually compiles. It doesn't with mine. The comparison against `NULL` is simply wrong, and shouldn't be there. That mistake happens for both files, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the files exist on the place you want your code to read them or simply create the files within your code

```
// using ofstream constructors.
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>  

std::ofstream outfile ("test.txt");

outfile << "my text here!" << std::endl;

outfile.close();
```

As pointed before, make sure your output files (output1.txt and output3.txt) are available and exist.